# is there something like brace expansion when using perl rename?

Tags: command-line, rename, perl

I have 100's of files that I want to remove the beginning numbers from. The files are named similar to below:

```
048banana.txt  
049pear.txt     
050watermelon.txt  
051tomato.txt    
062pepper.txt  
053potato.txt
```

my go to one-liner for this situation would be the following:

```
rename 's/048|049|050|051|052|053//g' *
```

since I have 100's of files to change it would be quite exhausting to write this out. Is there a method similar to brace expansion I could use to complete this. in a perfect world the command below would work great.

```
rename 's\{048..053}\\g' *
```

Comment: Well, you could always use your *shell's* brace expansion to target those files explicitly ex. `rename -n 's/^\d{3}//' {048..053}*.txt`

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. in fact it strips away the entire filename and just leaves an asterisk with an extension(*.txt)

Answer (score 1):

The closest equivalent in perl would likely be the [range operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) `..`

So for example, you could construct a regular expression and use it as follows:

```
$ rename -n 'our $re; BEGIN{$re = join "|", ("048".."053")} s/^$re//' *.txt
rename(048banana.txt, banana.txt)
rename(049pear.txt, pear.txt)
rename(050watermelon.txt, watermelon.txt)
rename(051tomato.txt, tomato.txt)
rename(053potato.txt, potato.txt)
```

The quotes around `"048"` and `"053"` are necessary to prevent the leading zeros from forcing interpretation as octal sequences.

Alternatively (and probably simpler), use the shell's brace expansion to limit the target of the replacement to those specific files, and then replace any 3 leading digits:

```
$ rename -n 's/^\d{3}//' {048..053}*.txt
rename(048banana.txt, banana.txt)
rename(049pear.txt, pear.txt)
rename(050watermelon.txt, watermelon.txt)
rename(051tomato.txt, tomato.txt)
rename(052*.txt, *.txt)
rename(053potato.txt, potato.txt)
```

The `g` modifier is not required in either case, since there is only one replacement per filename.

Note that shell brace expansion will attempt to rename `052*.txt` since you apparently don't have a matching filename with a `052` prefix - you could prevent that by setting `shopt -s nullglob` before running the command.